# Elastic nodes not sharing data?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

HI Currently I am using docker compose to spin up two instances of elastic containers and networking between them.

In one of the elastic containers i am executing a bulk api request to insert some documents to an index.

however the problem is when i separately logs into each elastic container and execute a curl command on of them shows the result and other not .

```
Prasanths-MacBook-Air:api kannan$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
798c06a9907b        docker_elasticsearch2                                 "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                 elasticsearch2
336e58a46217        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   elasticsearch
```

Now login on try curl command for listing each indices on each container

```
Prasanths-MacBook-Air:api kannan$ docker exec -it 798c06a9907b curl '127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
health status index uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   test  z27UBFUWTfC3E-xFFDhLOQ   5   1          0            0      1.2kb          1.2kb
yellow open   cars  R5mvqQk2RkuspNQ6o02E4g   5   1        833            0    491.6kb        491.6kb
```

Now trying the following

```
Prasanths-MacBook-Air:api kannan$ docker exec -it 336e58a46217 curl '127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
health status index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
```

This is my docker compose file named elasticsearch.yml using the following command

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml up
```

this is the content of the file elasticsearch.yml

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: elasticsearch/elasticsearch-Migration.Dockerfile
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

any idea why is the indices not listed properly when i execute a curl command on container elasticsearch and it works fine for container elasticsearch2

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this yml file, Hope this will work

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.master=true
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: elasticsearch/elasticsearch-Migration.Dockerfile
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - node.master=false
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```